# Python - SVM kernel and algorithm from scratch

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, svm

I am using SVM for three different kernels - linear, polynomial and radial, but I am getting the following error.

I have tried different methods, Is there any way I can fix my algo class or am I missing any function.

Here are my train and test data.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zRvxhVFSf-4keaUqQl6Vg2b26FaAgQnK

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-32145be147af> in <module>()
     21 plt.show()
     22 print("Predicting on Test Data")
---> 23 y_pred = svmLinear.predict(X_test)
     24 print("")
     25 print("Confusion Matrix")

<ipython-input-114-0ecf6ae6acd2> in predict(self, X)
    111 
    112     def predict(self, X):
--> 113         return np.sign(self.project(X))
    114 
    115     def project(self, X):

<ipython-input-114-0ecf6ae6acd2> in project(self, X)
    114 
    115     def project(self, X):
--> 116         if self.w is not None:
    117             return np.dot(X, self.w) + self.b
    118         else:

AttributeError: 'SVM' object has no attribute 'w'
```

And here is the code:

```
import numpy as np               # use this scientific library for creating & procesing arrays/matrices
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # Backend library for plotting
import matplotlib.colors
from matplotlib import style
from numpy import linalg
import cvxopt
import cvxopt.solvers
import pandas as pd
import sys


class SVM(object):
    """
    Support Vector Machine Classifier

    """

    def __init__(self, kernel=None, C=None, loss="hinge"):
        self._margin = 0
        print ("\n *******************Support Vector Machine Initialization*******************")

        if C is not None:
            self._C = float(C)
            print("\nC ->", C)
        else:
            self._C = 10000

        if kernel is None:
            self._kernel = self.linear_kernel
        elif(kernel is 'polynomial_kernel'):
            self._kernel = self.polynomial_kernel
        elif(kernel == 'gaussian_kernel'):
            self._kernel = self.gaussian_kernel

        #print("Kernel selected ->", self._kernel)

    #Input the data to this method to train the SVM
    def fit(self, X, y):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape
        #print("\n\nNumber of examples in a sample = ",n_samples , ", Number of features = ", n_features)
        self._w = np.zeros(n_features)

        # Initialize the Gram matrix for taking the output from QP solution
        K = np.zeros((n_samples, n_samples))
        for i in range(n_samples):
            for j in range(n_samples):
                K[i,j] = self._kernel(X[i], X[j])
                #print("K[", i,",", j, "] = ", K[i,j])

        # Here we have to solve the convext optimization problem
        # min 1/2 x^T P x + q^T x
        # s.t.
        #  Gx <= h
        #  Ax = b

        P = cvxopt.matrix(np.outer(y, y) * K)
        q = cvxopt.matrix(-np.ones(n_samples))
        #q is a vector of ones
        A = cvxopt.matrix(y, (1, n_samples), 'd')
        b = cvxopt.matrix(0.0)

        #G & h are required for soft-margin classifier

        if (self._kernel == self.linear_kernel):
            G = cvxopt.matrix(np.diag(np.ones(n_samples) * -1))
            #G is an identity matrix with −1s as its diagonal
            # so that our greater than is transformed into less than
            h = cvxopt.matrix(np.zeros(n_samples))
            #h is vector of zeros
        else:
            G_std = np.diag(np.ones(n_samples) * -1)
            G_slack = np.identity(n_samples)

            h_std = np.zeros(n_samples)
            h_slack = np.ones(n_samples) * self._C

            G = cvxopt.matrix(np.vstack((G_std, G_slack)))
            h = cvxopt.matrix(np.hstack((h_std, h_slack)))

        cvxopt.solvers.options['show_progress'] = False
        solution = cvxopt.solvers.qp(P, q, G, h, A, b)

        # Lagrange multipliers
        alpha = np.ravel(solution['x'])

        # Now figure out the Support Vectors i.e yi(xi.w + b) = 1
        # Check whether langrange multiplier has non-zero value
        sv = alpha > 1e-4
        self._alpha = alpha[sv]
        self._Support_Vectors = X[sv]
        self._Support_Vectors_Labels = y[sv]

        print ("\n Total number of examples = ", n_samples)
        print ("\n Total number of Support Vectors found = ", len(self._Support_Vectors))
        print("\n\n Support Vectors are: \n", self._Support_Vectors)
        print("\n\n Support Vectors Labels are: \n", self._Support_Vectors_Labels)

        #Now let us define the decision boundary
        #w = Σαi*yi*xi
        if (self._kernel == self.linear_kernel):
            for i in range(len(self._alpha)):
                #print(i, self._alpha[i], self._Support_Vectors_Labels[i], self._Support_Vectors[i])
                self._w += self._alpha[i] * self._Support_Vectors_Labels[i] * self._Support_Vectors[i]
        else:
            self._w = None
        print("\n Weights are : ",self._w)

        #b = yi − wT xi
        ind = np.arange(len(alpha))[sv]
        self._b = y[ind] - np.dot(X[ind], self._w)

    def predict(self, X):
        return np.sign(self.project(X))

    def project(self, X):
        if self.w is not None:
            return np.dot(X, self.w) + self.b
        else:
            y_predict = np.zeros(len(X))
            for i in range(len(X)):
                s = 0
                for a, sv_y, sv in zip(self.a, self.sv_y, self.sv):
                    s += a * sv_y * self.kernel(X[i], sv)
                y_predict[i] = s
            return y_predict + self.b

    def linear_kernel(self, x1, x2):
        return np.dot(x1, x2)

    def polynomial_kernel(self, x1, x2, p=3):
        return (1 + np.dot(x1, x2)) ** p

    def gaussian_kernel(x, y, sigma=5.0):
        return np.exp(-linalg.norm(x-y)**2 / (2 * (sigma ** 2)))

    def plot_linear_separator(self, X, y):
        plt.figure(1)
        #plt.subplot(221)
        for i in range(len(X)):
            if (y[i] == 1):
                plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], 'ob')
            else:
                plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], 'xr')

        slope = -self._w[0] / self._w[1]
        intercept = -self._b / self._w[1]
        x = np.arange(0, len(self._Support_Vectors))
        plt.xlabel("x1")
        plt.ylabel("x2")
        plt.title("SVM with linear separable case")
        plt.axis("tight")

        #plt.plot(x, (x * slope) + intercept, '--k')

        hyp_x_min = -5
        hyp_x_max = 20

        # (w.x+b) = 1
        # positive support vector hyperplane
        psv1 = (-self._w[0]*hyp_x_min - self._b + 1) / self._w[1]
        psv2 = (-self._w[0]*hyp_x_max - self._b + 1) / self._w[1]
        plt.plot([hyp_x_min, hyp_x_max], [psv1, psv2], 'k-.', linewidth=0.2)

        # (w.x+b) = -1
        # negative support vector hyperplane
        nsv1 = (-self._w[0]*hyp_x_min - self._b - 1) / self._w[1]
        nsv2 = (-self._w[0]*hyp_x_max - self._b - 1) / self._w[1]
        plt.plot([hyp_x_min,hyp_x_max], [nsv1,nsv2], '--k', linewidth=0.2)

        # (w.x+b) = 0
        # discriminant function
        df1 = (-self._w[0]*hyp_x_min - self._b) / self._w[1]
        df2 = (-self._w[0]*hyp_x_max - self._b) / self._w[1]
        plt.plot([hyp_x_min, hyp_x_max],[df1, df2], 'y')

    def plot_linear_margin(self):
        plt.figure(2)
        #plt.subplot(221)

        #we need to make three lines in total

        # w.x + b = 0,  
        a0 = -4;
        a1 = (-self._w[0] * a0 - self._margin ) / self._w[1]
        b0 = 4;
        b1 = (-self._w[0] * b0 - self._margin ) / self._w[1]
        pl.plot([a0,b0], [a1,b1], "k")

        # w.x + b = 1

        # w.x + b = -1
        #labels
        plt.xlabel("x1")
        plt.ylabel("x2")
        plt.title("SVM non-linear case")
        plt.axis("tight")
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `self.w` in the project function should be `self._w`.

Comment: I changed that, I am getting this error now. 

AttributeError: 'SVM' object has no attribute 'b'